# Batch path variable does not work in Windows Server 2016

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server

we recently switched from Windows Server 2008 to 2016 and we have some tasks to delete files and folders based on batch every day.

Here is the code:

```
set successful="D:\TEST\logs\successful.log"
set failed="D:\TEST\logs\failed.log"
set delpath="D:\TEST\1 und 2"

echo Logged time = %time% %date% >> %successful%
echo Logged time = %time% %date% >> %failed%

echo Files deleted: >> %successful%
echo Files failed to delete: >> %failed%

forfiles -p %delpath% -m *.* -c "cmd /c del /q @path && echo @path>>%successful% || echo @path>>%failed%"
forfiles -p %delpath% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path && echo @path>>%successful% || echo @path>>%failed%"

echo. >> %successful%
echo. >> %failed%
```

Since server 2016 this batch does not work.
Some issue with spaces in the path.

Output is:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'und'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

Could there be some changes in syntax of the path? Did I miss quotation marks?

Comment: Did you consider putting double quotes around `%delpath%`?

Comment: Just tried. No change.

Comment: Why are you using `ForFiles` instead of a `For` loop? If you want to continue with `ForFiles`, you really do need to use appropriately escaped doublequotes and/or replace special characters using their hex sequences. The help for the command, `Forfiles /?`, should provide some information to help you.

Comment: What's happening if you run the same command manually from a command line?

Comment: Do not use QUOTATION MARK characters in setting environment variable values. Use QUOTATION MARK characters when the variable is used. See @Compo's answer.

Comment: That certainly looks to be a bizarre bug. I cannot reproduce on my Win 10. There are multiple versions of FORFILES  that have different behaviors, but I've never seen what you are reporting. It appears FORFILES is not honoring the quotes around your path, so the whitespace causes `und` to be interpreted as another argument.

Comment: @lit - That is a good convention/programming style. But it is not a hard rule. There should be no problem including quotes in the definition, as long as you remember not to include an extra set of quotes when you expand.

Comment: Ok, so it is not an absolute rule. I have found it easy to get caught needing to use a quoted variable value with another variable that needs quotes. It can get complex quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of what I understand to be the same task, *(emptying `"D:\TEST\1 und 2"` and logging both failed and successful actions)*; but using `For` loops instead of `ForFiles` commands. Please feel free to give it a try and report back as necessary.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "successful=D:\TEST\logs\successful.log"
Set "failed=D:\TEST\logs\failed.log"
Set "delpath=D:\TEST\1 und 2"

(Echo Logged time = %TIME% %DATE%&Echo Files deleted:)>>"%successful%"
(Echo Logged time = %TIME% %DATE%&Echo Files failed to delete:)>>"%failed%"

For /D %%A In ("%delpath%\*")Do RD /S/Q "%%A" 2>Nul&&(>>"%successful%" Echo %%A)||>>"%failed%" Echo %%A
For %%A In ("%delpath%\*")Do Del "%%A" 2>Nul&&(>>"%successful%" Echo %%A)||>>"%failed%" Echo %%A

Echo(>>"%successful%"
Echo(>>"%failed%"
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. Will try it tomorrow and give u a reply.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with the name of the directory itself, but more with the fact if the directory is empty or not, as you can see in following experiment (I started adding an empty file "blabla.txt" in the directory, and I deleted it afterwards):

```
Prompt>forfiles /P "C:\1 und 2" /C "cmd /c echo @path"

"C:\1 und 2\blabla.txt"

Prompt>del "1 und 2\blabla.txt"

Prompt>forfiles /P "C:\1 und 2" /C "cmd /c echo @path"
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: That is a totally different error unrelated to what the OP is reporting